# How to make a <div> element blur at the top then return to normal at a certain point in the screen?

Tags: html, css

Ok so, im creating a blog page as a project and i have this idea of dynamic scrolling, there will a header that will disappear anyways when i scroll up and an image in the background overlapped by a div with the article that is blurry on the top, then when i scroll up and the image is out of view the blurry part goes back to normal,

i have no idea how to do that though, if anyone understands me please help :,)

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Give us an exmaple of your current code (or a minimal reproducible example as @MHD said) so it's easier for us to get a good idea of what you want :)